# 2D memory allocation

Tags: c++, arrays, string

I am trying to modify my program,

The prblem I am running into is actually the array of string allocation.

When trying to run the below program, I am getting the below error -

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

void function_manipulate(unsigned int **arr_str, unsigned int *arr_len)
{
    *arr_len = 3;
    int len = *arr_len;

//  *arr_str = (unsigned char *)malloc(sizeof(unsigned char *)*(*arr_len));
    arr_str = new unsigned int *[len];
    

    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        cout << arr_str[i] <<'\n';
    }
}

int main()
{
    unsigned int *array_string = NULL;
    unsigned int array_length = 0;
    
    function_manipulate(&array_string, &array_length);
}
```

The output looks like:

```
0
0
0
```

Comment: This is definitely not C as it's tagged.

Comment: Have you read it, what don't you understand there? `note: try removing the parentheses around the type-id`

Comment: And don't forget to take care of the second error. It's not much harder to understand, but you'll have problems making the fix fit in with the rest of the program.

Comment: I tried to modify my program, eventually the problem is not able to allocate array of 2d memory

Comment: Where is the _"below error"_?

Comment: The error is that the pointers are all zeros

Comment: There is no error here. This compiles fine. The way it is written is not great but it compiles and does what you are asking it to do. What are you expecting the output to be? the values of zeros are not bad one as in reality they are undefined values since you have never initialized them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you are trying to do.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

void function_manipulate(unsigned int **arr_str, unsigned int& arr_len)
{
    arr_len = 3;
    int len = arr_len;

//  *arr_str = (unsigned char *)malloc(sizeof(unsigned char *)*(*arr_len));
    *arr_str = new unsigned int [len];
    

    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        (*arr_str)[i] = 1234;
        //cout << arr_str[i] <<'\n';
    }
}

int main()
{
    unsigned int *array_string = NULL;
    unsigned int array_length = 0;
    
    function_manipulate(&array_string, array_length);
    
    if (array_string != NULL){
        cout << "array_length now is " << array_length << endl;
        for (int i = 0; i < array_length; i++)
        {
            cout << array_string[i] <<'\n';
        }
        delete[] array_string;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Note that this is pretty ugly and I would not recommend it. But it can be done.